# How can I use `monet-pimp` in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, monetjs

Reading [the package's description](http://monet.github.io/monet.js/), I see there are "extensions" on commonly used classes available in a separate file `monet-pimp.js`. For example, they suggest I write like this:

```
var f = function (x, y) { ... } .curry()
```

But I cannot understand how I am supposed to "activate" this feature. If I require the module:

```
monet = require("monet")
```

— I do not think any alteration to built in classes is to be expected. And I do not know if there is a way to require `monet-pimp.js` directly.

Answer (score 0):

the code is here; it's not exported;

https://github.com/monet/monet.js/blob/develop/src/monet-pimp.js

you can export it and use it like this..

```
...

export const activateMonadSugar = ()=> (function (root, factory) {
 ...
....


activateMonadSugar()
```